# Multiplicar matriz por array en c

Tags: c

estoy intentando multiplicar una matriz de números aleatorios por un array de números aleatorios y  me da el siguiente error:

> invalid operands to binary * (have 'int *' and 'int')

No entiendo de donde viene el error ya que no estoy usando punteros.

El error me lo da en la operación de multiplicación(qué está abajo del todo):

```
void main()
{
    int m = 5;
    int n = 4;
    int A[m][n];
    int x[n];
    int y[m];
    int i, j;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            A[i][j] = 1 + (rand()%999);
            x[i] = 1 + (rand()%999);
            y[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            y[m] = A[i] * x[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` es un array bidimensional... te falta indicar la segunda dimensión:

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        y[m] = A[i][j] * x[j];
//                 ^^^
    }
}
```